Prometheus windows_netframework_clrexceptions_exceptions_thrown_total shows a big spikes
We're running an ASP.NET MVC application (.NET Framework 4.7) in a Docker container (Windows cotnainer). We have a Prometheus windows_exporter running in that container and interested in the windows_netframework_clrexceptions_exceptions_thrown_total counter. I'm using this query increase(windows_netframework_clrexceptions_exceptions_thrown_total{instance="servername:9182"}[1m]) and the visual I've got have some spikes up to 600,000 which doesn't sound possible.

Is my query for this kind of visual correct? Is there any tools I can use to see what kind of exceptions were thrown? We use some unmanaged libraries so those exceptions could be unmanaged exceptions.

Query is OK. I think spike is here due to very short range interval and increase being only a wrapper around rate (of course i assume you checked metric itself, and it not containing any oddities). Generally in Grafana it is recommended to use $__rate_interval: it should be used here too.

@markalex - Thanks! I tried $__rate_interval as well and the results are similar. I looked at what prometheus scraped and I can see the numbers suddenly jumped. It's weird because my application behaves normally during those spikes. At this point, I just want to see what kind of exceptions were thrown during those spikes but unfortunately, it's just a counter.

Well, if your data has a sudden increase, than spike you see is expected and obviously not a fault of increase function.
